# Store textbox values in a div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox having id=add, a div having id=get and a button named Add. Now I'm trying to enter values in textbox, save them in to an array and then save that array elements in the div tag (using javascript). But I'm unable to do so. Please help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Content</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="stylesheets/keyword.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <SCRIPT language="javascript">
//            
            var data = new array();
            data= document.getElementById('add').value;
            function copy()
            {
                document.getElementById('get').innerHTML=data;

//                    document.getElementById('get').innerHTML= document.getElementById('add').value;
//                    return true;
            }
        </SCRIPT>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="add" id="add"/>
        <input type="button" name="but1" onclick="copy()" value="Add"/>
        <div id="get" class="keyword"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: at which point are you having problems?

Comment: *Now I'm trying to enter values in textbox, save them in to an array and then save that array elements in the div tag (using javascript).* So can we see your code? :)

Comment: Can you specialize your question, save values when user push add button or when user changes textbox value?

Comment: I'm pasting the code. When I write something in textbox and click on Add, 'undefined' is entered into the div.

Comment: can show raw o/p you want?

Comment: See I want to enter many values in the textbox and all the values should be stored in the array. And then the entire array (all items) should be shown in the div.

Comment: @Undervoter: Can I know why did you downvote this question? I mentioned that I couldn't do it inspite of trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Content</title>
    <script language="javascript">
        function copy() {
            var data = document.getElementById('add').value;
            document.getElementById('get').innerHTML += data + "<br/>";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="add" id="add" />
    <input type="button" name="but1" onclick="copy()" value="Add" />
    <div id="get" class="keyword">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS:Array (**not `array`**) is not required here,

Comment: Yes. List of values added from textbox to div tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `data` doesn't have any value, you are trying to read the value of the text box before setting a value and also it should be `Array()`

Try this instead

```
function copy()
{
     var data = new Array();
     data= document.getElementById('add').value;
     document.getElementById('get').innerHTML=data;


 }
```

[JsBin](http://jsbin.com/diyud/1/)

Comment: I want to show all the textbox values in the div as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Three issues in your code:

- `array()` is not recognized in javascript, it's `Array()`.
- You are trying to read the value of the text box before a value can be set to it here:

  `data= document.getElementById('add').value;`

  `function copy(){`

It should be:

```
function copy()
{
    data[0]= document.getElementById('add').value;
```

- `data` is an array. If you want to store a value, it should be used with an index.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8S9X/)

Comment: I want all the elements to be stored in the array and then the array items should be displayed in the div. How to do that?

Comment: What other elements do you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Content</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="stylesheets/keyword.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <SCRIPT language="javascript">
//
            var data = new Array();
            function copy()
            {

                data = document.getElementById('add').value; 
                document.getElementById('get').innerHTML = data;  document.getElementById('get').innerHTML= document.getElementById('add').value;
//                    return true;
            }
        </SCRIPT>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="add"/>
        <input type="button" name="but1" onclick="copy()" value="Add"/>
        <div id="get" class="keyword"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to show all the textbox values in the div as a list. When I write something and click on Add the value goe into the div but the 2nd time again new value is shown. I want to show all the textbox values.